# Mystery: Filevault not prompting for password after hard drive removed and reinserted

Tags: hard-drive, filevault, efi

I hooked up my 8,1 Macbook Pro's (A) fully Filevault 2-encrypted internal disk (El Capitan) to another Mac B (also El Capitan) externally to back it up. I had to input my Filevault password (every time) to access the disk, ran the graphical disk utility app's first help function on the disk which corrected some minor problem and after backup used diskutil eject to eject the disk (all on Mac B). The Macbook's (A) battery was disconnected for a few hours. When I put the disk back into my Macbook (A) (and reconnected the battery, obviously), there was no Filevault login, just a progress bar. It looks and feels to me as though the Macbook boots the system on the hard drive without the password. The boot does not complete beause my GPU is fried (that problem, yes). Can that be? Did disk utility app do sth. to the disk? Or is the Macbook booting the unencrypted recovery partition although I chose the recognized hard drive from the boot menu? Does anyone have an idea about what might be going on?

Comment: Post scriptum: what I ejected was the virutal disk, not the physical one. The virtual disk was shown as "locked encrypted" by diskutil list afterwards.

Comment: Post post scriptum: The only thing I can think of is that EFI mistakes the recovery partition for the main partition and boots that instead of the latter. Does anyone know how to fix that (if that's indeed what's going on)?

Comment: If you hold down the Option key on boot you should be able to choose the startup volume, to make sure it's not booting the recovery partition.